# Should be a matching if Statement (Textarea & Div)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, if-statement

I want to click on an item in the `removeFood` div and have it match to the item in the text area `newFoodName1`

```js
$(".removeFood").click(function() {
  var removedFood = ($(this).children('.dailyItem').text())
  $(this).text('')        
  var selectedFood = $("#newFoodName1").text();
  console.log(removedFood + selectedFood)

  if (removedFood == selectedFood) {
    console.log('They Match')
  } else { 
    console.log('they dont match') 
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='removeFood'> 
  <p class='dailyItem'>
    Eclair
    <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
  </p>
</div>    
<textarea id='newFoodName1'>Eclair</textarea>
```

In the console this logs `Eclair Eclair` However the if statement says they do not match. What am I missing?

Comment: just `trim()` both: `removedFood` and `selectedFood`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They do not match because of the whitespace around the values. If you use `trim()` to remove that, then the `if` condition is matched:

```js
$(".removeFood").click(function() {
  var removedFood = ($(this).children('.dailyItem').text())
  $(this).text('')
  var selectedFood = $("#newFoodName1").text();
  console.log(removedFood + selectedFood)

  if (removedFood.trim() == selectedFood.trim()) {
    console.log('They Match')
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='removeFood'>
  <p class='dailyItem'>
    Eclair
    <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
  </p>
</div>
<textarea id='newFoodName1'>Eclair</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

**just trim your data using trim()**

```js
$(".removeFood").click(function() {
  var removedFood = ($(this).children('.dailyItem').text().trim())
  $(this).text('')
  var selectedFood = $("#newFoodName1").text().trim();
  console.log(removedFood + selectedFood)

  if (removedFood == selectedFood) {
    console.log('They Match')
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='removeFood'>
  <p class='dailyItem'>
    Eclair
    <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
  </p>
</div>
<textarea id='newFoodName1'>Eclair</textarea>
```